# AngularJS rendering prevents progressbar update

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am loading objects via ajax.  Before I send the request, I put a progress bar on screen (using [pNotify](http://sciactive.com/pnotify/)) and update it using `setInterval`.

When the response is received, I dump the data objects into the scope and angular renders them all in an `ng-repeat`.  However, while it's doing this it locks up the browser - for about 3 seconds (acceptable, it's loading an entire document which includes hundreds of nodes, each containing ~2-5 directives).

This means my nice, animated progress bar stalls completely.

Is there a way to tell angular to let the progress bar continue animating (or prevent it from locking up the browsers) while it's rendering all my data?  Something like "DoEvents" in Visual Basic?

Comment: Hmm...my guess is that the mass amount of data completely locked everything up - is it possible to load the data a little at a time? Can the user see the entire amount of data all at once?

Comment: The data arrives, the browser locks up (but javascript continues to execute), then BOOM - the entire document appears and my progressbar "finishes" with a nice fadeout.  I'll go look into adding the data bit-by-bit, I kind of assumed that adding the data one object at a time would cause angularjs to re-render all the objects with each `scope.objects.push(newObj)`

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with angular but with the fact that js a single threated language. if you want your progress bar to continue working you should parse our information in a asynchronous manner. or load small chunks of data at a time, this means assign your ng-repeat to a small array and asynchronously increase it using a recursive function or simply a for look with a timeout something like

```
$scope.list=[];
$scope.list=$scope.list.concat(ajaxlist(0,20)); // adds the first 20 elements to the array
for(var i=21;i<ajaxlist.length;i++){
    (function(index){
       $timeout(function(){
           $scope.list.push(ajaxlist[index]);
       })
    })(i)
}
```

something like this should allow you to progressively increase your list. this should solve your problem of the freezed bar.

Comment: Understood... however, it appears `push`ing a new item doesn't update the DOM.  EG: This shows my content `$scope.list = ajaxlist` but this shows an empty document `$scope.list.push(ajaxlist[index])`, even though `$scope.list.length` = 740 after the last push.

Comment: you probably need to do $scope.$apply after the push

Comment: Yup - just did that now, and it does what I expected: each `push` causes Angular to render the whole array, making everything get exponentially slower :(  This turned the 3s wait into 83s.

Comment: but it shouldn't freeze your browser or hang your loading bar. also you could use the track by  expression in the ng-repeat to asociate the elements to the dom, asuming you have some sort of identifier in your data, that might help you with rendering the entire array on every push. other thing you could do if that doesn't work or gets too slow is to write a directive that builds the list asynchronously. but first try the track by option